# How to link between django views components

Tags: python, html, django, selenium, beautifulsoup

Actually, I am pretty new in Django. I have created three views in my views.py.
This is my following code in views.py :

```
from django.shortcuts import render 
import pymongo
from .models import *
from .serializers import *
from .forms import *
from .codes.scraping import scrap

def home_view(request):
    context = {}
    context ['form'] = Scraping()
    return render(request,'home.html',context)

def loading_view(request):
    return render(request,'loading.html')

def datatable_view(request):
    client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
    db= client["aliexpress_db"]
    col = db["segment"]
    products = col.find()
    context = {'products' : products}
    return render(request,'datatable.html', context)
```

My question is that I want to get a method in order to get the home_view first then my loading_view while the scraping is processing then my datatable_view.
I don't know how to link between these views. I am completely beginner. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

this is not a job for Django. I think what you want to do is possible through these steps:

1. place your loading gif/vector animation in your `home_view`
2. when the user submits the form show this animation using some javascript code until you get a response from `datatable_view` and change the page
3. pass the results to the template of `datatable_view` to render them.

alternatively, you can use an **AJAX Call** to receive the results in the home view.

checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59510573/how-can-i-show-a-loading-animation-in-django-while-the-server-is-processing-a-vi) would also help.

Comment: Could you please help me regarding your second point??

Comment: I don't know much about javascript. but a simple template is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59510648/10462931)

Comment: I can't understand your answer

Comment: Would be great please if you add further explanation so that I can understand your answer..